# How do I call a method from a dynamically added element in Vue

Tags: vue.js

Is it possible in Vue to insert a new element into the DOM and call a method from it in something like below?
The following does not work "nothing happens".

```
Popup() {
      const confirm = `
          <div>
            <div>Are you sure?</div>
            <div>
              <button @click="cancel" >CANCEL</button>
              <button @click="delete" >DELETE</button>
            </div>
          </div>
      `

      let div = document.createElement('div')
      div.innerHTML = confirm
      document.body.append(div)
},
delete() {
    console.log('deleted')
}
```

If it is not what would be the way to accomplish something similar in Vue?

Comment: This is pure html/ vanilla javascript. It's not connected to any Vue instance. You also manipulated the DOM directly by javascript instead of relying on the framework.

Comment: All clear, How is it to be done?

Comment: Ok, just write an element with all the events you want, make it dynamic with `v-if`. In Vue, dynamically means `v-if`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that Loi Nguyen Hunh!

Comment: Welcome man :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. We don't do that in VueJS. 
For this situation I would use v-if / v-show to achieve this.

```
<div v-if="isConfirm">
    <div>Are you sure?</div>
    <div>
      <button @click="cancel" >CANCEL</button>
      <button @click="delete" >DELETE</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Later in your data

```
data(){
    return {
        isConfirm: false
    }
},
method:{
    Popup(){
        this.isConfirm = true;
    }
}
```